# What is the time complexity of int('1010',2)?

Tags: python, time-complexity

I just want to know time complexity of `int(<binary string>,2)` in python, to convert base-2 binary number string to int

Comment: O(n), where n is the length of the binary string..

Comment: Well.. you have to go through the whole digits..

Comment: Yes, but it might be doing something more to create an integer after going through whole digits, will this add more complexity to the overall function?

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Python source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/longobject.c#L2012), converting from base 2, or any power-of-two base, is O(N) with respect to the number of characters.

```
/* *str points to the first digit in a string of base `base` digits.  base
 * is a power of 2 (2, 4, 8, 16, or 32).  *str is set to point to the first
 * non-digit (which may be *str!).  A normalized int is returned.
 * The point to this routine is that it takes time linear in the number of
 * string characters.
```

In contrast, it appears that every non-power-of-two-base is (usually?) [O(N^2)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/longobject.c#L2188).

```
Binary bases can be converted in time linear in the number of digits, because
Python's representation base is binary.  Other bases (including decimal!) use
the simple quadratic-time algorithm below, complicated by some speed tricks.
```